# Class does not show override methods from inheritance class

Tags: android, kotlin

I have created class `ScreenDrawer` that has 3 functions. And I have a class `ChatsScreen` that inherits the `ScreenDrawer`. But for some reason when I click Ctrl+O in Android Studio I don't see methods that I can `override` as I can do in `MainActivity` that extends `AppCompatActivity`.

So how I need to organize classes so my `ChatsScreen` could see `ScreenDrawer` methods by inherit it.

Here is my `ChatsScreen`

[image]

Here is my `ScreenDrawer` that need to be extended by `ChatsScreen`

[image]

Now I got this in methods

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any methods you want to `override` have to be `open` too (or already overridden, or `abstract`). [Check the docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inheritance.html#overriding-methods)

> The override modifier is required for `Circle.draw()`. If it were missing, the compiler would complain. **If there is no `open` modifier on a function**, like `Shape.fill()`, **declaring a method with the same signature in a subclass is not allowed, either with `override` or without it.**